# Is it possible to perform offline testing on my Web Browser on which features under HTML5 it support

Tags: browser, html5

I notice this website - http://html5test.com/ that I can test my web browser on which HTML5 features it support.

However, this mean that I will need to be online in order to test my web browser.

So, is it possible to test my web browser using a offline tools or script or something like the website but in a offline mode?

Comment: ...why would you need to do that?

Comment: to test on machine that are not allowed to be online due to policy restrictions.

Comment: But... if you are using a standard browser, you can just look up the results. Or test on an identical setup.

Comment: there are new browser that does not have any results yet.

Answer (score 0):

Not a pre-built solution I know, but you could always extract the pertinent javascript functions from the source data of the site and incorporate it as a locally-hosted site on the offline machines for testing purposes.

Eg.

- http://html5test.com/scripts/data.js ;
- http://html5test.com/scripts/useragents/detect.js?wxpwrnfd ; and
- http://html5test.com/scripts/engine.js

seem to be the ones you want